# HttpHostConnectionException - Android

Tags: android, iis, asp.net-web-api

Fiz no `Visual Studio Community 2013` um simples `Web API` pra registrar uma pessoa e receber uma pessoa, e estou tentando consumir esse serviço com um app android, estou emulando a aplicação pelo emulador `Genymotion`.


Quando ele faz o `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);` ele me traz uma exceção `HttpHostConnectionException` dizendo que a conexão ao `localhost` foi recusada.

O trecho de código está todo ok, mas caso queiram:

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpUriRequest method = null;
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            try {
                if (metodo.toUpperCase() == "POST")
                {
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                    post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(gson.toJson(object).getBytes()));

                    method = post;
                    method.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                }

                method.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                method.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);

                status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }
```

Já fui na documentação e chequei a parte `Emulator Networking`, e mesmo mudando de `localhost` para `10.0.2.2` ele continua não funcionando, mas quando mudo para `10.0.2.2` ele me traz que a conexão excedeu o limite de tempo e não que foi recusada.
Como proceder?

Comment: Já testou diretamente do seu aparelho? Pode ser algum problema com o emulador. Outra coisa: caso esse 10.0.2.2 é o IP da sua máquina onde o servidor está rodando?

Comment: to rodando o servidor na minha máquina local, e usando genymotion como emulador para o android

Comment: 10.0.2.2 é o IP da sua máquina na rede local?

Comment: Não, mas esse é o endereço que um emulador android reconhece como `localhost` segundo a documentação `Emulator Networking`

Comment: Você precisa colocar o IP da _sua máquina_ na rede local onde o **servidor** está rodando. Parece que você está tentando acessar o localhost do emulador.

Comment: o servidor é o localhost

Comment: A diferença é que o localhost do _emulador_ é diferente do localhost da sua máquina que é o _servidor_. Por isso você tem que acessar pelo IP dela na rede e não pelo localhost.

Comment: pra isso que serve o `10.0.0.2` mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: Acessa pelo navegador do android esse mesmo endereço e vê qual o resultado.

Comment: nem com o meu ip nem com o `10.0.0.2` ele funciona

Comment: Então é melhor você verificar se o servidor está rodando corretamente na sua máquina. Você já testou em um aparelho de verdade?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20199/discussion-between-andre-ribeiro-and-enzo-tiezzi).

Comment: Enzo, pesquisando sobre acesso ao localhost de um dispositivo, o pessoal em geral recomenda usar o ip `10.0.3.2`.

Comment: ja testei esse também, mas também não foi possível

Comment: Testando por fora do Genymotion, o Web Service está acessível?

Comment: sim, funcionando normalmente

Answer (score 1):

---

Se você está se referindo a um localhost do seu dispositivo use o `http://10.0.2.2/` em vez do `http://127.0.0.1/` ou `http://localhost /` .

Porque o seu emulador Android está sendo executado em uma máquina virtual (QEMU) e você não pode se conectar a um servidor que executa diretamente em seu PC.

Portanto, a sua url deveria está assim:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/SOMENTE_EXEMPLO_QUALQUER");
```

**Outra coisa, confira se no seu xml há esta permissão:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54626/discussion-on-answer-by-lollipop-httphostconnectionexception-android)

Answer (score 1):

Tente abrir a api desde o navegador do genymotion usando o inderezo ip de rede do computador (algo tipo 192.168.x.x)

Comment: eu fiz isso e também nada, utilizei o IP da VB, 192.168.56.1 e mesmo assim nada

Comment: a api pode ser accesada desde otro computador da rede...?

Comment: não fiz esse teste, até pq só quero que o emulador acesse ela, mas ela ta funcionando perfeitamente

Comment: So pra verificar mesmo, ten alguas veces que e preciso -'publicar' o acceso a web api dependendo da plataforma... 
No entanto se ten acceso na rede da pra testar en dispositivo fisico, infelizmente nunca tive ese tipo de inconveniente con o genymotion... tamben pode ser una configuraçao de subnet no vbox (genymotion usa vbox), se for isso o mesmo nao ten acceso a rede...